# Google maps Api 3 symbols

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

I would like to display on google maps a marker for my current position that I can rotate depending on the user's heading.

Currently only symbols can be attached to a marker and rotated (more here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols).

My challenge is that I want to use a custom symbol that looks like this (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5UD8mTDFqP7UHZ6bGpMeGpFR1U/edit?usp=sharing).

My problem is that the SVG file uses to define the shape a PATH and CIRCLE, but google API supports only path.

This is the SVG markup:

`<g>
    <g>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#ED6C61" d="M8.234,17.247c- .68,0-3.28-0.336-4.744-0.938c1.975,2.701,3.938,4.688,4.744,4.688s2.77-1.986,4.745-4.688C11.516,16.911,9.915,17.247,8.234,17.247z"/>
    </g>
     </g>
    <circle fill="#ED6C61" cx="8.235" cy="8.235" r="8.235"/>`

How do I obtain this shape by only using the path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single path of both objects.

Workflow(using inkscape):

1. **open the SVG**
2. **select the circle**
3. **convert the circle into a path:**
   <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+C</kbd> (or menu->path->object to path)
4. **select both pathes:**
    <kbd>CTRL+A</kbd>
5. **combine the pathes:**
   <kbd>CTRL+K</kbd> (or menu->path->combine)

Result:

```
 m 16.469999,8.2349997 c 0,4.5480643 -3.686935,8.2349993 -8.2349993,8.2349993 C 3.6869349,16.469999 0,12.783064 0,8.2349997 0,3.6869349 3.6869349,0 8.2349997,0 12.783064,0 16.469999,3.6869349 16.469999,8.2349997 z M 8.234,17.247 c -1.68,0 -3.28,-0.336 -4.744,-0.938 1.975,2.701 3.938,4.688 4.744,4.688 0.806,0 2.77,-1.986 4.745,-4.688 -1.463,0.602 -3.064,0.938 -4.745,0.938 z
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/LLH5s/